Копирование элементов XML разметки. Дублирование элементов
Проблема следующая. Есть LinearLayout внутри которого расположены 3 элемента (кнопка1, текствью, кнопка2). Мне необходимо сверстать 7 аналогичных по содержанию LinerLayoutов. Попытка копипаста привела к созданию ссылок на объекты. При изменении параметров кнопки, они применялись для всех аналогичных кнопок во всех копиях. Как быть? Неужели 7 раз одно и то же ручками собирать?

В IDE Visual Studio, например, можно создать сниппеты. Может и в вашем IDE есть что-то подобное? Погуглите

Подобные задачи гораздо лучше реализовывать с использованием XSLT.

Что ещё за ссылки? Показывайте что именно вы там делаете. Никаких проблем с копипастом быть не должно.

Делаете layout с элементами, что повторяются и включаете директивой include в 7 различных мест.

если вам надо чтобы сохранялся общий стиль и при изменении одного (например цвета кнопки, отступов, шрифтов и прочего UI), то лучшим вариантом будет сделать свою сборную Вьюшку и дать снаружи возможность задавать текст, вешать кликЛистенеры на элементы и прочую UI-логику, но не UI-дизайн.
хотя почему и не дать возможность менять цвет кнопок и текста? можно и это добавить. так даже лучше будет.
